# Japanese character in AdaptiveCard Bot Framework V4

Tags: c#, json, botframework, cjk, adaptive-cards

I have been trying to print a simple card with a Japanese character but it keeps displaying boxes and unknown characters.

This is how I create my adaptive card, then I get the params and data in a json, just to make it neat.

```
        string[] paths = { ".", "Cards", "pickLanguageCard.json" };
        string fullPath = Path.Combine(paths);
        var adaptiveCard = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);
        return new Attachment()
        {
            ContentType = "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            Content = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(adaptiveCard),
        };
```

Picture of the printed output:
[image]

As you can see the returned JSON data is also wrong. So this pinned it down to the main source of the Bot. I tried to the Json file containing the Japanese character, also change the encoding at the `web.config` but it didn't solve my problem. Back in Bot Framework v3, there is no problem in printing/displaying Japanese character. But when I tried v4 the Japanese characters get like that.

Any fix, solution, workaround will be appreciated. Thanks

Edit:
Tried using encoding param in `ReadAllText`, (Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.UTF32, Encoding.Unicode). In UTF8, other japanese character get to print but destroy the format of the Json unable to parse, also it occurs in utf32 and unicode. In default the character is the same.

Edit:
So after researching relentlessly, I found out that the JSON only encodes data to standard UTF-8 to make it lighter, and tried to using converting the characters to UTF-16 and it print successfully, but that seems wrong for me. Is there any other way to print correctly the Japanese characters?

Comment: Did you try to `ReadAllText` by specifying the encoding? `shift_jis` or `euc-jp`

Comment: Yup tried those

Comment: Can you explain what you mean in your most recent edit? JSON is a format but a JSON file is just a text file. You can encode it however you want. Why does it seem wrong to you to encode the characters as UTF-16?

Comment: @KyleDelaney Sorry I didn't said it clear, I mean that I convert it literally to UTF-16, Like あ = \u3042, and the `ReadAllText` successfully read the Japanese character.

Comment: That seems like a good solution. Why does that seem wrong to you?

Comment: @KyleDelaney sorry late reply, weekend. Well you see it's not understandable by the eyes of the human (in the first look), making it harder to edit a simple single letter in a paragraph/sentence/phrase printed as UTF-16.

Comment: Do you want to store your Japanese text in a separate UTF-16 resource file and load that text into the Adaptive Card dynamically? Or do you want a solution that allows you to edit the Japanese text in the card directly?

Comment: @KyleDelaney as the what the code said, I get the resource in JSON file, the JSON file consist the Adaptive Card information, but because of the requirements of the chatbot the JSON the encoding is a UTF-8 and thus Japanese characters become a diamond/box with question mark. So my workaround I converted the string to unicode UTF-16 (/u0061) and it works perfectly. I really don't want to store it to another file and read it because it will take another set of memory just reading the another file. Thanks btw

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you edit JSON in Visual Studio 2019 and try to save the file with Japanese characters, Visual Studio will automatically offer to fix the format for you:

[image]

If you want to manually save your file with a specific encoding instead of relying on an automatic dialog box, you can use the Save with Encoding... option in the File > Save As... dialog:

[image]

If you select Codepage 65001, which is Unicode (UTF-8) with or without signature, your Japanese characters should display correctly:

[image]

Comment: I already tried that, I saved it in different encoding too, but `File.ReadAllText(fullPath);` get and parse the japanese characters into boxes.

Comment: @Francisaskquestion - Since it is working for us but not for you, can you try to provide more relevant details to help us find the operative difference? If you'd like to attach the file itself in an email, I would be willing to try to resolve this in a private conversation.

Comment: I love to resolve this but the work around I made was already accepted and the project already transition to another part, so basically the problem is resolve. Thank you and sorry to take you time though

Comment: @Francisaskquestion - Don't forget to upvote this answer and mark it as correct